# Unable to insert document in Mongodb collection using python script

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I've written a script in python to populate a Mongodb data base using pymongo. Upon running the script, I get the following log:

```
cmd command: insert { $msg: "query not recording (too large)" } keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:48 reslen:40 175ms
```

Upon researching online, I found out that this has to do with the maintenance of the two types of logs which Mongodb generates and not with document insertion.

Then, just to check, I modified the following code in my script

```
connection.dbName.collectionName.insert(document)
```

to

```
print connection.dbName.collectionName.insert(document)
```

The output that I'm getting, which are the `_id's` of the document entered:

```
...
149  record entered
54636c409c2e912fbf433622
150  record entered
54636c409c2e912fbf433623
151  record entered
54636c409c2e912fbf433624
152  record entered
54636c409c2e912fbf433625
153  record entered
54636c409c2e912fbf433626
154  record entered
...
```

The `_id's` are being generated, but when I use `db.collectionName.findOne()` in the mongo shell I get `null` as output. 
I must also make clear that the Mongodb server is running on a NUMA machine. Looking online I was able to resolve this issue. 
Please help me in resolving this problem.

**UPDATE**

The following are the logs of the mongo server:

```
2014-11-12T21:43:36.742+0530 [conn24] allocating new ns file /data/db/db-name.ns, filling with     
zeroes...
2014-11-12T21:43:36.916+0530 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/db-name.0, filling   
with zeroes...
2014-11-12T21:43:36.924+0530 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/db-name.0, size: 
64MB,  took 0.007 secs
" }operties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "db-name.collection-name 2014-11- 
12T21:43:36.925+0530 [conn24]    added index to empty collection
query: { _id: ObjectId('546387309c2e9132e0a2f6f8'), //rest of the document} ninserted:1 
keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:183005 183ms
2014-11-12T21:43:36.925+0530 [conn24] command AVAYA-IVR.$cmd command: insert { $                                                                                              
msg: "query not recording (too large)" } keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros)                                                                                           
w:271 reslen:40 183ms 
2014-11-12T21:43:38.100+0530 [conn24] end connection 127.0.0.1:56906 (1 connection now open)
2014-11-12T21:43:59.811+0530 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:42 virt:665
2014-11-12T21:43:59.811+0530 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):480
2014-11-12T21:43:59.811+0530 [clientcursormon]  connections:1
2014-11-12T21:48:59.823+0530 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:43 virt:665
2014-11-12T21:48:59.823+0530 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):480
2014-11-12T21:48:59.823+0530 [clientcursormon]  connections:1
2014-11-12T21:53:59.835+0530 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:43 virt:665
2014-11-12T21:53:59.835+0530 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):480
2014-11-12T21:53:59.835+0530 [clientcursormon]  connections:1
2014-11-12T21:57:01.028+0530 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56909 #25 (2  
connections now open)
2014-11-12T21:58:59.847+0530 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:42 virt:665
2014-11-12T21:58:59.847+0530 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):480
2014-11-12T21:58:59.847+0530 [clientcursormon]  connections:2
```

This is all that the log says. Something which I do not understand is that the log shows just the first document which is entered. Is this the source of my troubles?

Comment: Sounds like you are issuing `.findOne()` with the "string" value of the `ObjectId` and not an actual `ObjectId`. Typically such abstraction is only performed by higher level libraries than the basic drivers. Either that or "wrong collection" or "wrong db" or server or whatever.

Comment: I found a work around for the problem. I pickled the data (which is hashmap) and then unpickled it and inserted it in the collection. This worked. Still, I'm I'm not able to understand why I'm not able to populate the collections without this work around. The data is not even that large, about 500000 documents.